# In Chrome, page won't scroll up (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scroll

Bottom of the page, clicking '**Send us your resume**' should scroll to browser to the top of the page. Works in IE, FireFox, but in Chrome it refuses to scroll up.

Code:

```
    /*
     * Scroll to "Show Form", and Focus on first field in form
     */
    $('#goto-show-form').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#show-form").offset().top}, '1000', 'swing', function() {
            $('#first-field').focus();
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I hid the URL I had posted on here because I didn't want it indexed by Google. It's a website I made for client, and when they search their URL, I prefer it doesn't show any of the development talk that went into making their website.

But to see the initial error, check out: http://jsfiddle.net/rgPpE/12/ As you can see in Chrome, when you click the link at the bottom, it won't scroll. However, if you add something between the `<a></a>` tags, like `&nbsp;`, it will now scroll to there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>I can't test this right now, so I'll delete if this isn't the correct answer, but</s> try scrolling to a non-empty element, like `#send-resume`.

```
$('#goto-show-form').click(function() {

      // --non empty target for the scroll---v
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#send-resume").offset().top}, '1000', 'swing', function() {
        $('#first-field').focus();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Perhaps there's a bug in version 12.

---

**EDIT:** Verified. Targeting a non-empty element fixes the issue.

Comment: @codemonkey613: Just got done testing it myself. Glad it worked. :o)

Comment: Originally, I was using <a name=""></a> for the jump links, and thought - hmm, might be fancy with a jQuery scroll. So then I ended up using that id for the jQuery. But looking back, I see now it was pointless to keep using that for the id.

Answer (score 1):

In your scrolling animation function, I see you're providing the duration as a string. Try providing it as an integer:

```
$('#goto-show-form').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#show-form").offset().top}, 1000, 'swing', function() {
        $('#first-field').focus();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Good catch on that, but it wouldn't actually prevent the animation from working. It would just always be set to the default. [Here's the source for that.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L327-328)

Comment: Thanks. I wrote this code a year ago when I first got into jQuery. I didn't even notice this until now :)